# Marginal distributions of abs. cont. random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following theorem:

$$f_{X_2}(x_2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_1$$

And I am confused about how to set the lower and upper bounds. For instance I have had two problems regarding this topic. First one;

Let
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      4(xy-x^2) & 0<x<1, \quad x<y<x+1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

Find $f_Y(y)$ for all $0<y<1$. (I know the answer) therefore I figured the following:

$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^y4(xy-x^2)dx=\frac{2}{3}y$$

Here the upper bound is $y$. And in the 2nd:

Let 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & 0<x<1, \quad x<y<x+1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

Find $f_Y(y)$ for all $1<y<2$. I get the following:

$$f_Y(y)=\int_y^2 1dx=2-y$$

Here $y$ is the lower bound. I am confused about this, how do I know what my bounds are supposed to be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y):=\begin{cases}
      4(xy-x^2) & 0<x<1, \quad x<y<x+1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

and fix $y \in (0,1)$. Then

$$\begin{align*} f(x,y) \neq 0 &\iff x \in (0,1), x<y, x>y-1 \\ &\stackrel{y \in (0,1)}{\iff} x \in (0,1), x <y \\ &\stackrel{y \in (0,1)}{\iff} 0<x<y. \end{align*}$$
 Consequently,

$$f_Y(y) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx = \int_0^y 4 (xy-x^2) \, dx.$$

---

Now consider

$$g_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}
      1 & 0<x<1, \quad x<y<x+1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$

and $y \in (1,2)$. Then

$$\begin{align*} g(x,y) \neq 0 &\iff  x \in (0,1), x<y, x>y-1 \\ &\stackrel{y \in (1,2)}{\iff} x \in (0,1), x>y-1 \\ &\stackrel{y \in (1,2)}{\iff} y-1<x<1. \end{align*}$$

Consequently,

$$g_Y(y) = \int g_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx =  \int_{y-1}^1 \, dx = 2-y.$$